# Different length and merge

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, merge, matching

I have two datasets (one for each population: `sellers` vs `buyers`). They are built in the same way.

```
FOR BUYERS (TYPE 2)
period subject genderb gp matchp treatment type p1 p2 suminte partner
1      1         0      2    48     404      2   7  8    NA     4
1      3         1      2    48     404      2   7  8    NA     4
...

FOR SELLERS (TYPE 1)
period subject genders gp matchgp treatment type p1 p2 suminte partner
1       4        1      2    48     404       1   7  8    2     NA
...
```

However there are less observations in the `sellers` data because one seller can be matched with many buyers in one `period` (here, the seller interacted with 2 buyers). In the `buyers` data, partner indicates the `subject id` (column subject of the seller), while in the `seller` data `suminte` indicates the number of buyers the seller interacted with.

What I would like to do is: in the dataset `buyers`, for each row add the column `genders` (meaning gender of seller), and matching it with the right buyer, at the right `period`, in the right group, matching group with the right prices...

The outcome I'd like to have is as follows:

```
FOR BUYERS (TYPE 2)
period subject genderb genders gp matchp treatment type p1 p2 suminte partner
1      1         0        1     2    48     404      2   7  8    NA     4
1      3         1        1     2    48     404      2   7  8    NA     4
...
```

Let me know if I am not clear enough...

Comment: You need to merge your datasets using the appropriate columns. I'll post a solution based on what you've mentioned, but it will be good to have more data to make sure we're using the right columns to merge.

Comment: Also, in `df1` you have a column named `matchp` and in `df2` you have `matchgp`. I'm using `matchgp` in both in my solution.

Comment: There is no difference between matchgp and matchp, it's only an error from me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# example data
df1 = read.table(text = "
                 period subject genderb gp matchgp treatment type p1 p2 suminte partner
                 1      1         0      2    48     404      2   7  8    NA     4
                 1      3         1      2    48     404      2   7  8    NA     4
                 ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = read.table(text = "
                 period subject genders gp matchgp treatment type p1 p2 suminte partner
                 1       4        1      2    48     404       1   7  8    2     NA
                 ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)

# remove columns that exist in df1 and you won't join on them
df2 = df2 %>% select(-treatment, -type, -suminte, -partner)

# join datasets using appropriate columns
left_join(df1, df2, by=c("period","gp","matchgp","p1","p2", "partner"="subject"))

#   period subject genderb gp matchgp treatment type p1 p2 suminte partner genders
# 1      1       1       0  2      48       404    2  7  8      NA       4       1
# 2      1       3       1  2      48       404    2  7  8      NA       4       1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in your output, it doesn't seem that the column "genders" has been added to buyers' data frame.

Comment: It's because I exclude it from `df2` by mistake. I'll update my solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have more (and last) related question :  in select(-treatment, -type, -suminte, -partner, -subject), can I do this :  select(-[10:251]) if I want to remove columns 10 from 251 (since I have 251 variables in both dataframe, and I don't want them to be twice in the merge process) ?

Comment: You can use base R for that. For example if you want to keep the first 3 columns of dataset `mtcars` you can do `mtcars[,1:3]`

Comment: I tried your solution, and in fact I guess you forget an important element : matching partner and subject. In my exemple buyers 1 and 3 were matched with seller 4 indicated in the column partner. And the information about the id of the seller is reported is the column subject of seller dataframe. Maybe we have to us by.x=c and by.y=c ?

Comment: I've updated the solution to match partner and subject.

Comment: PERFECT FIT! :D